# How to exclude \n and \r from tell() count in Python 2.7

Tags: python

I want to keep track of the file pointer on a simple text file (just a few lines), after having used `readline()` on it. I observed that the `tell()` function also counts the line endings.

My questions:

1. How to instruct the code to skip counting the line endings ?
2. How to do the first question regardless the line ending type (to work the same in case the text file uses just `\n`, or just `\r`, or both) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tell` is `tell`. It counts the number of bytes from the start of the file to the cursor. `\n` and `\r` are bytes, so they get counted. If you want to count the number of bytes, but not count certain characters, you will have to do it manually:

```
data_read = … # data you have already read
len([b for b in data_read if b not in '\r\n'])
```

The bad news is that it's far more annoying to do this than just looking at `tell`. The good news is that it answers both your questions.

or, I suppose you could do

```
yourfile.tell() - data_read.count('\r') - data_read.count('\n')
```

Comment: First version works well, the second only takes \n into account and appears to ignore the \r. Will use the first 'manual' way, thanks.
As for "tell is tell", I was thinking (obviously wrong) that the tell function will not count control characters if the file is open in non-binary mode.

Answer (score 3):

You are navigating into trouble. 
DOn't do that: either use the number "tell"  tells you about, or count what you have in memory, regardless of the file contents.

You won't be able to correlate a position in text, read in memory, to a physicall place in a *text* file: text files are not meant for that. They are meant to be read one line at a time, or in whole: your pogram consumes the text, and let the OS worry about the file position.

You can open your file in binary mode, read its contents as they are into memory, and have some method of retrieving readable text from those contents as needed - doing this with a  proper `class` can make it not that messy.

Consider the problem you already have with the line-endings which could be either "\n" or "\r\n" and still count as a single character, and now, imagine that situation one hundred fold more complex if the file has a single utf-8 encoded character that takes more than one byte to encode.

And even in binary files, knowing the absolute file pointer position can only be useful in a handful situations where, usually, one would be better using a database engine to start with.

Comment: You are right generally speaking, except that in my particular case I don't care about it or prefer a 'fixed' linear approach (it's a small text array of 8x8 ASCII characters, always the same size in binary representation (00101001\n01001001\n...etc., 8 lines total), related to a hardware audio matrix/router protocol; direct binary numbers were easier to handle or the string could as well be single 64x1 row, but the config file is supposed to be also be human readable, somewhat like a visual on/off matrix shape).
As for database, hm, good point, I will remember that [for more complex tasks].

Comment: In Python, if you want to end with a list with the 8 numbers encoded in binary in the file "numbers.dat", you can do: `numbers = [int(line, 2) for line in open("numbers.dat") if line.strip()]` (the filter on "line.strip()" is to avoid processing blank lines )

Answer (score 0):

```
result = re.sub("[\r\n]", "", subject)
```

http://regex101.com/r/kM6dA1

```
Match a single character present in the list below «[\r\n]»
   A carriage return character «\r»
   A line feed character «\n»
```